# Binding to @count of an array in the user defaults

Tags: xcode, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

Is it possible to bind a Control to collection properties of an array stored in the user defaults?

I was attempting(in interface builder of Xcode 4.3) to bind the Max Value to the arrays count like this:

**Max Value  (Shared User Defaults Controller.values.MYArrayName.@count)**
**bind to:** shared user defaults controller
**controller key:** values
**Model key Path:** MYArrayName.@count

Unfortunately this has no effect at all (not even any errors).

I can bind the Max Value to an ivar in the view controller then bind that to the value from the user defaults.
e.g

```
NSUInteger maxVal
...

NSUserDefaults* stdUD=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[self bind:@"maxVal" toObject:stdUD withKeyPath:@"MYArrayName.@count" options:nil];
```

Then:

**Max Value  (File's owner.maxVal)**
**bind to:** files owner
**controller key:**
**Model key Path:** maxVal

But I would have liked to do it with out the extra step

Comment: In the programmatic versino you left out the "values" in the key path. Maybe that's part of the reason?

Comment: I tried removing it before but it is necessary. But your comment made me realise that in the XIB i'm binding to the shared user defaults **controller** but in the code it is to the standard user defaults object.

Comment: The documentation for values says "_Returns a key value coding compliant object that is used to access the user default properties_", and "_This property is observable using key-value observing_", so I would have thought it would work. Obviously I am missing something else as well.

Comment: Well, I was just wondering why your programmatic sample was working even though you had left out the "values"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the standardUserDefaults with Interface Builder, with 2 options:

### First Option

In Interface Builder, drag in a User Defaults Controller to Objects.

Then, drag in an NSArrayController, and name it something like "ArrayFromDefaultsController" (just for clarity's sake). Make sure it's mode is Class, and Class Name is NSArray (or NSMutableArray).

In the bindings tab, under Content Array:

**Bind**: User Defaults Controller

**Controller Key**: values

**Model Key Path**: <#your Key#>

Go to your field, and bind it's Max Value:

**Bind**: ArrayFromDefaultsController

**Controller Key**: arrangedObjects

**Model Key Path**: @count

This simply creates an Array Controller that is bound the the array in your user defaults, and the field is bound to the count value of that Array Controller's arrangedObjects.

### Second Option

Create an NSValueTransformer subclass (eg. ArrayCountValueTransformer), and in the class put this:

```
+(Class)transformedValueClass {
    return [NSNumber class];
}

- (id)transformedValue:(id)value {
    if (value == nil) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        return [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[value count]];
    } 
}
```

This will automatically convert the count of your User Default's array to a value recognizable in the Model Key Path.

Drag in a User Defaults Controller into the objects list. Then, in the field you want to bind (on Max Value):

**Bind**:User Defaults Controller

**Controller Key**: values

**Model Key Path**: <#your key#> (no @count)

**Value Transformer**: ArrayCountValueTransformer

Comment: I can't really remember asking this question or what I did after but these seem good answers so I will mark it as the accepted answer.